# How to organize HTML with CSS block content in Django

Tags: html, css, django, structure

**I would like to ask what is a good approach creating a Django block content for a website.**

The main idea is that it's going to be a simple website, mostly focused on displaying an image.

I want to know if it's a good idea to create ***FrontEnd*** part of a website using Bootstrap 4 library where main BackEnd part is create in Django framework ?

I would like to simplify the production part using template form to display different part of main page, and I want to ask if it's a good solution?

First I created one html file which should include all specific part of webpage(header, content part, footer)

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Second I create a navbar html file

```html
{% block content %}
    <header id="main-navigation">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="main-navigation">
                <li class="home">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home_view' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact_view' %}">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="logo">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logo_view' %}">Logo</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

At the end I want to include footer part of a website

```html
{% block content %}
    <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer part</p>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to know as well if using MODAL would be a good solution if I want to put fixed navbar with footer, and scrollable content, for example for displaying images.

I hope that I specify more the question!

Comment: Are you asking how to organize your template files or (as the title states) how to set _height_ to different blocks? Or you're asking whether this is a good idea to use same block name `{% block content %}` in different page parts or not?

Comment: Sorry, actually I probably ask for all of this. Because I am confused with this. I know it's three different topic, but I was trying to include it inside one question

Comment: Please split it into different questions. Your question is not specific. Also I have no idea what does "height" question mean. As of "the structure": Django states that template inheritance works faster then including - that's it.

Comment: @mmalak in my opinion, it's a good idea to modularize your templates. For example, if you have components that you know will have very specific needs for different javascript libraries, you can create a block and override the parent. You could organize your main index file as your "driver and include engine" for your modular components (other template files you include in your index file). This is one of the approaches I've taken in the past.

Comment: @chennighan so essentially you think that organize the main html file as driver is a good approach, and in the next step for each module (navbar/content/footer) add as a engine to the main file?

Comment: @mmalak you would extend the main html file and then override the content block with whatever you are going to put inside of it. Each section of your site (presumably) will have a top level template. For example: you have your main html file that acts as the driver which includes everything that will be shared across all the templates that will be extending it and overriding the content block. Does that make sense?

Comment: @mmalak I've added an answer with an example base file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a good idea to modularize your templates. For example, if you have components that you know will have very specific needs for different javascript libraries, you can create a block and override the parent. You could organize your main index file as your "driver and include engine" for your modular components (other template files you include in your index file). This is one of the approaches I've taken in the past.

you would extend the main html file and then override the content block with whatever you are going to put inside of it. Each section of your site (presumably) will have a top level template. For example: you have your main html file that acts as the driver which includes everything that will be shared across all the templates that will be extending it and overriding the content block.

Example base file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block meta %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    {% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}your title override{% endblock title %}</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}"/>
    <!-- LOAD CSS FILES -->
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% include 'path/to/your/stylesheets.html' %}
    {% endblock stylesheets %}
</head>

<body>
{% block header %}
    {% include 'path/to/your/header.html' %}
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
<br>
<br>

{% block footer %}
    {% include 'path/to/your/footer.html' %}
{% endblock footer %}

<!-- Load JS last for load times -->
{% block javascripts %}
    {% include 'path/to/your/javascripts.html' %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can just have this in your view:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse


def index(request):
    context = {}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'path/to/your/template.html', context)
```

Comment: @mmalak i don't know what you're asking, sorry

Comment: Sorry I am not good in specify questions properly.. But you actually give me a specific answer for what I have been looking for. You did it right now adding  above answer !

Comment: But what if one of view loading context ? and it's specify in block content html file? What should be included in urls file?